# Windows Phone 8 get foreground application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way to get current foreground application, by some background process or application running in background?

I would like to make a history of user's activity. In Android we can use package manager and get running applications. Is there a similar approach in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: No, in Windows Phone, apps (and especially background agents) are fairly limited and you can't get access to that. (It *might* be malicous and therefore Microsoft chose to forbid it *all* the times. In my opinion, it is not a very smart move, but you can't change it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. there is no any API or any other technique available to do that as of now in Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks. Hope they will give us such ability in the next releases.

Comment: Yeah, You can give developer feedback to Microsoft go to this link http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform here and explain your need and get developers to vote for it. Then may be it will be added in to the next release. Donno for sure. :)

Comment: And if the answer is satisfactory to your please mark it as correct :)

Comment: I just added my need to the developer's feedback. Thanks for help.

Comment: I just voted for it :) Hopefully, it gets the attention.